# Wpf textbox does not change borderbrush when trigger mouse over?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

In my WPF application I want to to change borderbrush color for a TextBox when mouse enter, but it does not change color to the one I want, but it change to sky blue (I guess it is standard color).

Here is my XAML code:

```
 <Window x:Class="OnePlayApp.Views.LoginDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OnePlayApp.Views"
        WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Title="LoginDialog" Height="350" Width="550" Foreground="Black">

    <Grid Background="#282828">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="24*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="43*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="43*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="59*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="191*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Margin="9,10,173,6" Source="/Resources/logo.png" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>


        <Label x:Name="AccountName" Content="Account name" Margin="6,10,1,13" Foreground="#FFAFADAD" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Label x:Name="Password" Content="Password&#xD;&#xA;" Margin="6,10,1,13" Foreground="#FFAFADAD" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="2"/>

        <TextBox x:Name="username" Margin="6,11,15,8" Background="#FF282828" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" Text="Ahsep12015@one.com" FontFamily="Yu Gothic UI Semibold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="10">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />

                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
        <PasswordBox x:Name="password" Margin="6,8,15,13" Background="#FF282828" Password="123456789" FontSize="18" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

        <Button x:Name="LoginBtn" Content="Login" Margin="6,15,15,146" Click="LoginBtn_Click" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Yu Gothic UI Semibold" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFAFADAD"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#79B539"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="CancelBtn" Content="Cancel" Margin="6,15,15,146" Click="CancelBtn_Click" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Yu Gothic UI Semibold" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFAFADAD"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#79B539"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>

        </Button>



    </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Comment: " - thanks." < - You mean this is Your XAML code ?

Comment: Hi @petethepagan-gerbil I tried to upload my XAML code but it does not show up in my question?

Comment: This won't work. Best solution would be to create a control template for this textbox and inside control template set your triggers

Comment: This code works fine for me, the border goes red (I set the border thickness to 10 to see the effect clearly) (edit to show code is pending).

Comment: Hi @petethepagan-gerbil. How come mine does not? Whenever I hover over the textbox it goes skyblue?

Comment: Do you have any other styles anywhere else?

Comment: Hi @petethepagan-gerbil I just added my whole XAML code. The style for the buttons works as it should.

Comment: @LocDaiLe, that works for me too. Just straight copied and pasted it into a new project. Does it work for you in a completely new project?

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil I'm on win10 do you think it could be something with that? - Let me try with a new project.

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil I tried on a whole new WPF project and it did not work either. I am running win10 and VS15. My first textbox borderbrush is green form the start but when I hover over it it change to skyblue.

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil which win and VS do you use?

Comment: I've tried both now. Win7 VS2015 works fine as you've written it, Win10 VS2015 does not. I've not done a lot in Win10 yet but I will have a look into it. From what I can see, it's as if the MouseOver trigger isn't firing at all.

Comment: Hi @petethepagan-gerbil. Thank you for your respons. If you find out why Win10 does not fire the trigger please let me know.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in Windows 8.  Always sky blue regardless of the trigger BorderBrush color.  Interestingly, the BorderThickness property in the trigger gets set just fine.  But the color doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue on Windows 8, and the only way I was able to fix this issue (which appears to be a bug in WPF) was with a ControlTemplate.  This is the standard control template for a `TextBox` as coughed up by Blend.  I changed the BorderBrush colors, added it to my global TextBox style, and it works great.  There may be a better solution out there, but this is what works for me.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Orange"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```